# How can a ChoiceField.choices callable know what choices to return?

Tags: django-forms

In Django 1.8, the `ChoiceField`'s `choices` argument can accept a callable:

```
def get_choices():
    return [(1, "one"), (2, "two")]

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_choices)
```

In the above example, `get_choices()` always returns the same choices. However, being able to assign a callable to `choices` does not make much sense unless that callable knows something like, say, an object id, each time it is called. How can I pass such a thing to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do it in the form declaration because [the CallableChoiceIterator calls the function without arguments](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8714403614c4dfa37e806db4a6708b8a91a827a4/django/forms/fields.py#L809) [that he gets from here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8714403614c4dfa37e806db4a6708b8a91a827a4/django/forms/fields.py#L838). 
Doing in the `__init__` Form method is easier than creating your own ChoiceField I guess. Here is what I suggest:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Let's pass the object id as a form kwarg
        self.object_id = kwargs.pop('object_id') 

        # django metaclass magic to construct fields
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Now you can get your choices based on that object id            
        self.fields['my_choice_field'].choices = your_get_choices_function(self.object_id)
```

That supposes that you have some Class Based View that looks that has a method like this :

```
class MyFormView(FormView):
   # ...

   def get_form_kwargs(self):
       kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
       kwargs['object_id'] = 'YOUR_OBJECT_ID_HERE'
       return kwargs

   # ...
```

*P.S : The super() function call supposes you are using python 3*

Comment: Your choice supply method `get_choices()` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: @jnns It's defined in the question

Comment: yes, you're right. But I find it very confusing and unnecessary to have that function there if it's never invoked and in fact overwritten in `__init__`.

Comment: I see what you are talking. That makes sense. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's possible to set a callable like that is to avoid situations where you're using models before they're ready.

`forms.py`

```py
class Foo(ModelForm):
    choice_field = ChoiceField(choices=[
        user.username.lower() for user in User.objects.all()
    ])
```

Were `forms.py` imported before models were ready, (which it probably is because `views.py` generally likes to import it, and `urls.py` generally likes to import *that*, and `urls.py` is imported by the startup machinery), it will raise an exception due to trying to do ORM stuff before all the apps are imported.

The correct way is to use a callable like so:

```py
def lower_case_usernames():
    return [user.username.lower() for user in User.objects.all()]


class Foo(ModelForm):
    choice_field = ChoiceField(choices=lower_case_usernames)
```

This also has the benefit of being able to change without restarting the server.