# Setting relationship with chosen model class in Django Admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

**Problem:**
How to add relationship from chosen model instance to any other Django model dynamically via Django Admin interface?

**Description:**

I want to create `Categories` via Django Admin interface. Each `Category` has multiple `Choices` assigned to it. `Choice(s)` from given `Category` may be assigned only to objects of another specific Django class (model). Let's present a pseudocode example:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField()


class Choice(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="choices")
    choice_name = models.CharField()


class ModelWithChoosableFields(models.Model):
    possible_categories = ...   # objects of class Category
    selected_choices = ...   # objects of class Choice

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Book(ModelWithChoosableFields):
    ...

class Animal(ModelWithChoosableFields):
    ...
```

- `Category` with `category_name = 'Genre'` has three possible
  `Choices`: `choice_name = 'biography'`, `choice_name = 'thriller'`
  and `choice_name = 'poetry'`.

  `Category` with `category_name = 'Animal type'` has two possible
  `Choices`: `choice_name = 'mammal'` and `choice_name = 'reptile'`.
- Class `Book` may have one of the `Choices` from `Category`
  `category_name = 'Genre'` assigned. However, `Choices` related to
  `category_name = 'Animal type'` cannot be assigned to class `Book`.

  Analogically, class `Animal` can only have `Choices` related to
  `category_name = 'Animal type'` assigned to it.

In other words, in Admin panel for instance of class `Book` I want to have a way of selecting `Choice` objects from `Categories` appropriate for `Book` class.

The reason I want to do this is so that user using Django Admin interface can add dynamically possible Categories to chosen models (e.g. add `Category` `category_name = "Conservation status"` choosable for class `Animal`), add more Choices to Categories if needed (e.g. add another `choice_name = 'fish'` to  `category_name = 'Animal type'`. This way it is very flexible for end admin user, no need to change anything in code.

I tried achieving it with Generic Relations - however, it wasn't successful, because AFAIK generic relation ties given object (e.g. `Category`) to **instance of object** of any other class, not generally to **any other class** (so, when using Generic Relations, for `Category` I would have to specify relationship with given `Book` object instance, not with `Book` class in general).

I wonder if such action is even feasible - I searched a lot and couldn't find anything. Maybe there is a simpler way? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are `Choice` and `Category`,  do they extend `models.Model`?

Comment: @Alex yes, they do. Edited the question. Thank you

Comment: The term "choice" needs improvement. It doesn't really mean anything in the context you are using it, and it's going to be confusing because of Django's `ChoiceField`. Finding better names for these entities is an exercise in philosophy, but a quick idea is to use `CategoryType` for what you've been calling "category" and `Category` for what you've been calling "choice".

Comment: "This way it is very flexible for end admin user, no need to change anything in code." To me, however, it looks like premature optimization and YAGNI. I'm also skeptic re how useful it will be if the user can't define new entities (`ModelWithChoosableFields` subclasses; btw, `ModelWithChoosableFields` also needs a better name).

While [ChoiceField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731225/how-can-a-choicefield-choices-callable-know-what-choices-to-return) may help you, I believe that what you are looking for doesn't exist out-of-the-box.

Comment: How about a many to many relation between `category` and each of your models? The admin can select which categories are assigned to each `Book` or `Animal` from the admin panel, and as choices are related to a category, `Animal`s and `Book`s will be connected to their choices via this many to many relation.

Answer (score 0):

### With [ContentTypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttype-model) you can relate model instances to entire model classes, no overwriting necessary to achieve your goal.

Heres how to do it:

1. In your Category model define a [many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) to ContentType. This way, in your Category model-forms you will be able to choose which models this category applies to and you will be able to filter Choices based on whether their category contains a particular model. Use the *limit_choices_to* parameter of the ManyToManyField to restrict the ContentType choices to those with the correct app_label and of course exclude the Choice and Category models.
2. From the Book/Animal/Etc. models add [many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) to the Choice model  and use the *limit_choices_to* parameter to limit the Choices to only those with a category which is related to the respective model.

Your models should then look somewhat like this:

```py
from django.db import models


def get_ContentTypes():
    appQ = models.Q(app_label='YourAppName') #change value of app_label to match your app's name
    modelIsCatQ = models.Q(model='category')
    modelIsChoice = models.Q(model='choice')
    return appQ & ~modelIsCatQ & ~modelIsChoice

class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    asigned_models = models.ManyToManyField(ContentType,limit_choices_to=get_ContentTypes)

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.Model)

class Animal(models.Model):
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choice,limit_choices_to=models.Q(category_assigned_models__model__startswith='animal'))

class Book(models.Model):
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choice,limit_choices_to=models.Q(category_assigned_models__model__startswith='book'))
```

Aaand Voila. There you have it:

1. When creating/editing a category, you choose which models it should apply to
2. When creating/editing a Book/Animal/etc. you can only see the relevant choices.